# Firestore write operation not executed on second sign up attempt from same device

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I have been at this the entire day and I still cannot figure it out or find any help online. I am pretty sure it's something very small I am missing. I will do my best to explain my issue.

I have a Vue.js SPA with Firestore and Firebase-Authentication. Today I noticed some weird behaviour from my app and I think it has something to do with cache. So I have SignUp component in which I have the following:

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
    .then(
      function(user) {
         firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user.user.uid)
          .set({
            firstname: _this.fName,
            lastname: _this.lName,
            username: _this.uName,
            email: user.user.email
          })
          .then(() => {
            _this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', {email: user.user.email, uid: user.user.uid})  
            
            _this.$router.replace("/HomeUserPage");
          })
          .catch(function(error) {                
            console.log("Error signing up:", error);
          });
  },
      function(err) {
         console.log(err.message, "this is an error");
      }
    )
```

I also have my SignOut handler like this in another component:

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(() => {
      this.$router.replace("Login");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
     
    });
```

My problem is the following: Whenever I log out and try to create a new user(Sign Up), it works perfect the first time. Then I log out, and try to Sign Up one more user and what happens now is I get the user created, however, the call to the firestore database in the callback of .createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not executed, hence, my route doesn't change and my data doesn't get populated.

What I have found so far: This is doesn't happen if I reload the page after logout(Hence, why I think the problem is coming from cache).

Do you have any thoughts why this is happening, is it expected behaviour and I am just expected to reload the page after each logout ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Apparently, it's a bug as Doug mentioned above, so I went to post it on Github and it has been already reported:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3218

It was a problem in the older version (7.15), which has been fixed now (7.16). So just updated my Firebase SDK and all works as expected now.